# How to Create Line Break on Google Maps Engine Lite

Tags: google-maps

I am editing a map in Google Maps Engine Lite and when I add a marker and description, it doesn't let me make a new line. Enter saves what I wrote, and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> don't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has stumped me for a while and finally I found a solution on the official Google forum. The solution is that you need to press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

**Update:** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> seems to work now as well.

Answer (score 1):

@Ynhockey is correct, alt + enter gives a full paragraph break (2 lines).

For a single line break (next line), press `Alt` + `Command` + `Enter`